# How to extend called callback from another function

Tags: javascript

I'm not sure about what title I need to use or what I need to call what I'm gonna do, here is the problem

there is a code in `sortable.js`

```
var sortableStuff;

    sortableStuff = {

        sortableList = $('#mySortable');

        init: function(){

           sortableList.sortable({

              start: function(){

                  lot of codes here... 

              },

              stop: function() {

                  another codes here..
              }
           });
        }

    }
```

I want to extend the start and stop function from another another file for example `mysortable.js` but still run the start and stop callback from the one above.

```
sortableStuff.sortableList.sortable({
       start: function(){
           run the code from the start before..

           run my new code
       }
})
```

I'm not a javascript expert, and don't know what to call what I'm trying to do here, please help me.

Comment: What `sortable` plugin are you using? Link its docs! How does it allow you to access old callbacks, and does it allow you to overwrite them at all?

Comment: I used jquery ui sortable

Answer (score 1):

You've got a syntax error in your first script, mixing object literals with variable assignments. It should be

```
var sortableStuff = {
    sortableList: $('#mySortable'),
//              ^                 ^
    init: function() {
        this.sortableList.sortable({
//      ^^^^^ use as a property
            start: function(){
                // lot of codes here... 
            },
            stop: function() {
                // another codes here..
            }
        });
    }
};
```

Now you can access `sortableStuff.sortableList` from outside, and depending on how your `sortable` plugin works be able to extend/add/overwrite callbacks.